# Answer of $5 - 0 \times 3 + 9 / 3 =$

Tags: arithmetic

According to order of operations the answer should be $\mathbf{2}$ 
But Google and Wolfram calculates as 8

**This is last proccess: $5-0+3$**

This is how I think: $5-(0+3)$

This is how Google answers: $(5-0)+3$

So, question is which operation is first $+$ or $-$?

Comment: Why is there a vote to close as not a real question? Looks like a question about mathematics to me.

Comment: Verily, this is a real question about expression parsing, which can be delicate matter of interest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You proceed from left to right down the hierarchy.
$$5- 0\cdot3 + 9/3 = 5 - 0 + 3 = 5 + 3 = 8.$$
You make the mistake of distributing the $-$ to two terms in the absence of parentheses.

Comment: Could be computers automatically removes '-0' someone told me something like that. According to her, -0 represents nothing.

Comment: That would be an error in the code for their parser.  We know $-0 = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

The operations + and - have the same priority, therefore google is right: $a - b + c$ is read as $(a-b) + c$.

Answer (score 2):

$\times$ and $\div$ are higher precedence than $+$ and $-$, but each are associated left-to-right. First, the multiplication and division. Next, the leftmost addition/subtraction. Finally, the last addition.
$$
\begin{array}{c}
5-\color{#C00000}{0\times3}+\color{#C00000}{9/3}\\
\color{#C00000}{5-0}+3\\
\color{#C00000}{5+3}\\
8
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The $0$ is meant to "confuse" but if you write things in a very explicit $+,\times$ only notation it gets clearer:

$$\begin{align}
&5-0\times 3+9/3 =\\
&5 + (-1)\times 0\times 3 + 9/3 =\\
& 5 + 0 + 3 = 8
\end{align}$$

Remember that $a-b$ is actually $a+(-1)b$, and multiplication takes precedence over addition, so $(-1)\times 0 + 3$ is not the same as $(-1)\times(0+3)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$5-(0+3)=5-0-3=2$$ 
but
$$(5-0)+3=5-0+3=8$$
There's no priority between $+$ and $-$, but most people prefer to start from right to do the calculation.

Comment: As far as I always knew (and I haven't taught this stuff since my last kid was in junior high), the order between product/division and sum-substraction gets determined from left to right.