# What is the result of $5-0\times3+9/3=$?

Tags: arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answer of $5 - 0 \times 3 + 9 / 3 =$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179958/answer-of-5-0-times-3-9-3)

What will be the answer of

$$ 5-0\times3+9/3 = ?$$

if we follow BODMAS? Please explain each step.

Comment: $5-0*3+9/3 =5-(0*3)+(9/3)$ as '*' has precedence over  '-' and '+',  '/' has precedence over '+'.  $=>5-0*3+9/3 =5-0+3$

Comment: Why don't you either learn how to type with latex in this site (pretty easy) or at least tray to separate the expressions to udnerstand what is it? Is it $\,5-0\times3+\frac{9}{3}\,$ , or perhaps $\,5-\frac{0\times 3+9}{3}\,$ , or $\,5-0\times\frac{3+9}{3}\,$ , or something else?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : To me it seems uncouth to write $0*3$ instead of $0\times3$ or $0\cdot3$.  The only reason anyone ever used $*$ for that purpose is that when one is restricted to the characters on the keyboard and one wants to use x as the name of a variable in computer programs, one must use something else for $\times$.  But we have $\TeX$ and we don't need to do that.  It's like eating mashed potatoes with your fingers when silverware is available.

Comment: @DonAntonio It is my first question . I will learn latex.

Comment: @Serious, since this is your first question on math.SE, please don't take this question closure as a hostility against you (or new users), and don't get discouraged to post further questions. It's just that this site works better if we re-cycle and re-use existing questions and answers, and then tag/label duplicate questions & link them together.

Comment: @Serious puro bal chhal

Answer (score 0):

$$5-0\times 3+9/3=5-0+9/3=5-0+3=5+3=8$$

Assuming, of course, the above is what you meant to write.

Comment: Shouldn't we add 0 and 3 before subtracting. ?

Comment: @Serious see [this colorful answer by robjohn♦](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/183295/2468).

Answer (score -1):

The original expression becomes 5-0+3, which is 8. 
By the way, this shouldn't have the tag (linear-algebra). Put it in arithmetic.

Comment: Fixed the tag .

Comment: The second part really ought to be a comment, not in an answer, and the first part isn't very well explained.